# install spring boot application in centos not working

Tags: linux, spring-boot, service

i want to run a spring boot application by using java -jar, first, i use maven to package is to execable jar, then i put to linux server, and i install it as a system service, i can run it by `service xxx start` ,but it still log the boot messages in front, if i closed the session, the app will exit again, so how to keep the applicaion run as a service in backend?

and i followed this [article](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use below commands

```
service xxx start &

jobs  -- you should see above app running if not then no issue else run below command

disown
```